# Trace individual dimensions using PYMC3's traceplot?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, bayesian, pymc3, mcmc

I have used PYMC3 to perform inference on a Bayesian logistic regression model. I want to find the posterior over the weights $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^K$ given a Gaussian prior $\mathcal{N} \sim (0,I)$ .

This is using real, not simulated data represented by the design matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times K}$ and binary outcome vector $y\in \mathbb{R}^N$.

My Python code is as follows:

```
with pm.Model() as logistic_model:
    # 14 dimensional Gaussian prior
    beta = pm.Normal('beta', mu = 0, sd = 10, shape = X.shape[1])

    # Expected value of outcome with sigmoid link
    logit_p = t.dot(X, beta)
    pm.Bernoulli('likelihood', logit_p=logit_p, observed=y)

    with logistic_model:
    # Inference
    trace = pm.sample(2000)
```

I then proceed to use

```
pm.traceplot(trace)
```

to get a visualisation of the posteriors. This outputs the following:

[image: Click for image]

I'm curious; how I would go about plotting each dimension of the posterior on separate sub-plots? It looks rather messy having them all on one!

Apologies for the dollar signs - I'm new to this and unsure how to display math correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [arviz](https://github.com/arviz-devs/arviz), which can be installed with

```
pip install arviz
```

Then you can use

```
import arviz as az

az.traceplot(trace)
```

Which works as you describe.

[image: traceplot from arviz]

Note `arviz` is still somewhat unstable, but should replace `pymc3`'s plotting functions within the next few month.

Comment: Thats great, thanks very much!
One other thing - would it be possible for me to overlay another Gaussian distribution of my choosing onto each of these plots?

Comment: both `arviz.traceplot` and `pymc3.traceplot` return an array of axes (in the above case it will be 4 x 2).  The easiest way will probably be to grab that (`axes = az.traceplot(trace)`, and then manually plot in each axis (`ax[0, 0].plot(my_x, my_y)`)

Comment: What is the meaning of `trace` in `traceplot`?

Comment: The timeseries of draws (on the right in the above plots) is called a trace. I do not have a citation for that!